# TextureView surface is not available on Samsung S3

Tags: android, android-camera, textureview

Running following [TextureView demo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) on Samsung S3 4.0.4 produces black screen on other devices it works just fine. `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` callback does not get called and camera is not initiated.

Adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to actvity tag in manifest produces following error, `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` get called though.

Am I doind something wrong? Is there a workaround ?

**Stack trace**

```
03-04 13:26:53.210  23410-23410/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
            at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:349)
            at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:326)
            at com.example.myapplication.LiveCameraActivity.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(LiveCameraActivity.java:25)
            at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:343)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2877)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11170)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10606)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10604)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11170)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2298)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10606)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:842)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2108)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1832)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code snippet**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.TextureView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LiveCameraActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private TextureView mTextureView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

        setContentView(mTextureView);
    }

    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Something bad happened
        }
    }

    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        // Ignored, Camera does all the work for us
    }

    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        return true;
    }

    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        // Invoked every time there's a new Camera preview frame
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding your solution to your question as an edit, add is as a self-answer and remove it from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware acceleration is mandatory for `TextureView`. The exception was thrown because I was missing `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` in AndroidManifest.xml. The thing is that, hardware acceleration should be enabled on 4.0.4 on default.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to TextureView. java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service. This exception is thrown when another application is using camera, or you called `Camera.open()` earlier in your code and forgot to release it.

You should open camera in `onResume` and release in `onPause` or `onStart/onStop`.

Comment: This error only occurs when `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`. When I open camera in onResume it throws the same error.

Comment: TextureView requires `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to work at all, so if you disable it you're probably not getting to your Camera open call at all because the callbacks aren't firing.

Comment: Oh right. Does it mean that android 4.0.4 needs to be specifically told that `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` but other versions have this implicit ?